# get couple of data from mysql to android apps

Tags: android

i have a table in mysqldatabase named Person
using this code i can retreive just the image from mysql database using phpScript :

```
@Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        String add1 = "http://192.168.1.11/save/load_image_from_db.php?id=1";
        URL url;
        Bitmap image = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(add1);
                HttpURLConnection connection =(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(connection.getInputStream());
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) { e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace();}
        return image;
    }
}
```

and this is **phpscript load_image_from_db.php**

```html
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","othmane") or die(mysqli_error($con));
  
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){
$id = $_GET['id']; 
$sql = "SELECT image,image_type FROM images where id = $id";

$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));;
  
$result=mysqli_fetch_array($r);
header('Content-Type:image/jpeg');

if ($result['image_type'] == 'php') {
            echo ( $result['image']);
   } else if ($result['image_type'] == 'android') {
            echo base64_decode( $result['image'] );
        }
mysqli_close($con);
//stripslashes ($result['image']);
//echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['image'] ).'"/>';
//echo base64_encode( $result['image'] );
}
?>
```

if i change this php script so it shows the image and the id, how can i get these data to android apps is there something like ResultSet ?

Comment: You're going to need to parse the data coming back from a post request, so you'll need to parse XML or HTML.  You might want to consider a service.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I just use a POST Request that grabs the data provided by PHP. Gets the job done.

In Android it's a bit involved, but I create a PostHandler class (it has to extend AsyncTask to do web work). Then you have the doInBackground and callServiceHttpPost methods (which I believe are part of an interface). I call the service post method from the do in background. Then I use HttpClient and HttpPost to do the work.

Finally you have an onPostExecute method.

You create this class, then create an instance of it in your main program, and do .execute() to run it. You can pass in params through a custom method.